# Flow workflow not showing up on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

So I have created a number of workflows using flow, and have set them up to execute when a new item is created in my SharePoint lists. All of my flows execute correctly, and manage to even correctly manipulate different parts of this SharePoint.

However, when I look onto the actual SharePoint task list and any lists holding what the flows that are associated with the site, I cannot find them listed there.

How can I get the SharePoint to recognize these flows as being associated, and to save the flows on its directory?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible. Not now at least. It seems that Sharepoint can't show any data about connected flows at all. The only way I see now, to give flow special name associated with SP list, so you can quickly recognise it between all other flows.